# Unlocking additional campaigns

Tags: starcraft-2

I have Starcraft 2: Legacy of the Void on my PC, and I have the Wings of Liberty disc. How can I unlock the Wings of Liberty campaign without reinstalling the whole game?

Comment: IIRC, you just need to add a code to the Battle.net account and the campaign will be available to play after a game update, but I'm not 100% sure, especially since you say you have it in a disk form. Have you simply tied installing it from the DVD?

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to https://www.blizzard.com/
2. Log into your account.
3. Go to Account Settings and then Account Overview if you're not already there.
4. There should be a box at the top of the page that says **Redeem a Code**.
5. Enter your code from the DVD in that box.

It should then add *Wings of Liberty* to your account.  If it doesn't, click the **Support** link (upper right of the page) and explain how you got the DVD, what you tried to do, and what you expected to happen.

If it is showing on your account on the website but not in the game, try shutting off the game and rebooting your computer.  If it's still not working, back to the **Support** link on the Blizzard site.

Note:  this won't work if someone has already used the DVD to install the game with that code.  In that case, the DVD is useless to you.  Because the right to *play* the game is not associated with the DVD but the installation code.  If you're unsure if the code was ever used, that's why you contact Support.  They can look up whether the code was used.